# Selenium 3.0.1 - Safari 10 Webdriver - NoSuchWindowException after setPosition

Tags: java, selenium, safari, webdriver

My Selenium node starts and registers to my Selenium grid succesfully. Then when delegated to run a test by the hub, opens a new safari window, loads our page and then hangs, leaving the page open and throwing a NoSuchWindowException. Console output is as follows:

```
INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
INFO - SessionCleaner initialized with insideBrowserTimeout 0 and clientGoneTimeout 1800000 polling every 180000
INFO - Executing: [new session: Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=ANY}]])
INFO - Creating a new session for Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=ANY}]
INFO - Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
INFO - Detected dialect: OSS
INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=ANY}]]
INFO - Executing: [implicitly wait: 15000])
INFO - Done: [implicitly wait: 15000]
INFO - Executing: [get: TEST_PAGE_URL]
INFO - Done: [get: TEST_PAGE_URL]
INFO - Executing: [implicitly wait: 15000])
INFO - Done: [implicitly wait: 15000]
INFO - Executing: [set window position])
WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: A request to use a window could not be satisfied because the window could not be found. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds

after some system information :

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteWebDriverOptions$RemoteWindow.setPosition(RemoteWebDriver.java:852)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringWindow.setPosition(EventFiringWebDriver.java:628)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.SetWindowPosition.call(SetWindowPosition.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.SetWindowPosition.call(SetWindowPosition.java:27)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
WARN - Exception: A request to use a window could not be satisfied because the window could not be found. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 15 milliseconds
```

The following is the chain of methods that initialises the webDriver and leads up to calling setPosition, where the problem occurs:

```
private void initTest(String testName, String testPage)
   {
      WebDriver driver = this.createDriver(testName, testPage);

      ..........
   }

private WebDriver createDriver(String testName, String testPage)
   {
      WebDriver driver = null;
      driver = createRemoteDriver(webDriverName, testPlatform);
      initDriver(driver, testPage, testName);

      return driver;
   }

private void initDriver(WebDriver driver, String testPage, String testName)
   {
      final String TEST_PAGE_URL = deployUrl + testPage;
      driver.get(TEST_PAGE_URL);

      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.manage().window().setPosition(DEFAULT_ORIGIN);

      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.manage().window().setSize(DEFAULT_BROWSER_SIZE);

      .........
   }
```

I'm running OSX Sierra, the Selenium 3.0.1 server jars, and the new Safari 10 Webdriver for Selenium 3 as described here: https://webkit.org/blog/6900/webdriver-support-in-safari-10/

I have tried adding implicit waits and the like after the initialisation of the driver, in case the timing issues that seem to be blamed for this exception in various other cases could have been to blame, unfortunately without seeing any difference.

I don't know whether my page simply hasn't fully loaded by the time Selenium tries to set its position, however would have expected the addition of the implicit waits to have fixed it if this was the issue.

To conclude, Is this a known issue with the Safari 10 web driver, or one that others have encountered?