# How to set window size for Safari browser running codeception / selenium 3.3.1

Tags: selenium, safari, codeception

Working on upgrading our Codeception acceptance test suite from Selenium 2.53.1 to Selenium 3.3.1.  When running on Selenium 3.3.1, our Webdriver option of window_size: seems to have no effect.

- I've tried using 'maximum'. This leads to the test running on a window maybe a third of the size of my approximately 1420 x 700 screen.
- I've tried using a specific size '1400 x 600'. This leads to an error "A request to use a window could not be satisfied because the window could not be found."
- When tests are run with window_size removed they run in the same size window as when it is set to 'maximum'.

Our normal, maximum, continues to work for Firefox and Chrome on Max OSX Sierra when run with selenium server 2.53.1 or 3.3.1. Safari bit from acceptance.suite.yml:

```
env:
    safari:
         modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    browser: 'safari'
                    window_size: 'maximum'
                    clear_cookies: true
                    restart: true
                    options:
                        cleanSession: true
```

I note there is another unanswered question on Stack Overflow referencing a similar error running selenium 3.0.1 with no answer [Selenium 3.0.1 - Safari 10 Webdriver - NoSuchWindowException after setPosition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792202/selenium-3-0-1-safari-10-webdriver-nosuchwindowexception-after-setposition).

Comment: you can try this solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44007020/1372688

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah i have similar problems, this is a known defect, for safari and safari technology preview: i quote:

Selenium 3.1.0
Safari 10.0.3 or Safari preview V25
UnsupportedCommandException   for is Displayed NOT FIXED
and maximize does not work and surely there will lot more

Comment: Moe where did you find that detail?  I'd like to mark the site so I can follow for updates.  Thank you!

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-users/xEGcK92rzVg
see the last comment in this Thread, Im waiting and checking for updates daily in hopes that this gets resolved.

Comment: Accepting this answer as I can't find any mention of it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Safari 11 with Selenium 3.5.3 this issue is resolved.  Simply including window_size: 'maximize' works again.