# How to set open safari preview in protractor

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, safari, protractor

Because safari has a issue with resize windows and this bug has been fixed in Safari Preview. However, i don't know how to open safari preview in protractor (i installed it). I tried below setting but it does not work.

```
capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'safari',

        safariOptions: { technologyPreview: true }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:
  { browserName: 'safari', 'safari.options': { technologyPreview: true } }

Comment: can you elaborate a bit? i'm assuming this worked for you?

Comment: Yes. It works. I got it after searching on the internet. But I assume that some people have same question so i still keep this question.

Comment: nice, I think you should too, however you should add this information to your answer, as well as link(s) to wherever you found the info, plus what the code does.